# No picture after installing firmware on amd gpu

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, amdgpu

Black screen after boot then i installed firmware. No console, no x, no log, no picture at all. Video driver not seen monitor.

tryed Linux 4.19.0 and 5.3.0 on debian

```
cpu: AMD A6-7480 Radeon R5, 8 Compute Cores 2C+6G


00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo (rev e6)
```

Connected with ssh i run

```
DISPLAY=:0 xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-1 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

But i have only Dsub on board!

dmesg

[    1.614589] [drm] Unsupported Connector type:5!

Comment: both. thnx, found workaround

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: i cant delete this question. but i think it usefull for ubuntu too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="amdgpu.dc=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1"`

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105880

not works in 5.x Linux